# What is the condition for example $(number^c)^b=number^{cb}$ to be true?

Tags: arithmetic

What is the condition for $(\text{number}^c)^b=\text{number}^{cb}$ to be true?

I can't find it on google.ze so I asked it here on math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

For positive real numbers it's always true. Counterexample for negative numbers: $((-1)^2)^{1/2} = 1^{1/2}=1$ but $(-1)^{2\cdot 1/2} = (-1)^1 = -1$.

Comment: you write $1^{1/2}=1$. But also $1^{1/2}=-1$ doesn't look wrong to me :)

Comment: $1^{1/2}=-1$ looks very wrong to me since $x^{1/2}=\sqrt{x}\geq0$