# Is $\left((-1)^2\right)^\frac12 = (-1)^\left(2\cdot\frac12\right)$?

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic, exponentiation, square-numbers

I'm feeling confused. If I square 1 and -1, the answers should be equal:

$1^2 = (-1)^2$

Then I take both sides to the power of $\frac12$:

$\left(1^2\right)^\frac12 = \left((-1)^2\right)^\frac12$

This next step seems to make sense according to the simple arithmetic rule about multiplying exponents:

$1^\left(2\cdot\frac12\right) = (-1)^\left(2\cdot\frac12\right)$

And then comes the weirdness:

$1^\left(\frac22\right) = (-1)^\left(\frac22\right)$

$1^1 = (-1)^1$

$1 = -1$

Obviously I did something wrong... Every step seems perfectly reasonable except going from step 2 to step 3. That seems reasonable too, that's what I was taught about exponents, but that's the only step which I could conceive has special constraints I violated. Is $\left((-1)^2\right)^\frac12 = (-1)^\left(2\cdot\frac12\right)$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/664383/1242

Comment: @HansLundmark, so $\left(x^a\right)^b = x^\left(a\cdot b\right)$ only when x is positive? Why is that? I guess I intuitively felt that, but still don't understand why. If a number is multiplied by itself m number of times and that whole thing is multiplied by itself n number of times, then the original number must've been multiplied by itself mn times...

Comment: That's true for integer exponents, but how do you multiply something with itself a half number of times?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sqrt{1} = \pm 1$. By squaring, you end up with [extraneous solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraneous_and_missing_solutions).

Another example is trying to solve $x=2$. By squaring both sides, we get $x^2 = 4$, which has solutions $x=2$ and $x-2$, hence $-2=2$, which is nonsense.

Comment: the radical is defined as the positive square root, so it can't be -1 just by definition. In your example, it's not a problem for x to be both 2 and -2, that doesn't mean 2 = -2.

Comment: It is a problem for $x=-2$, since this is not a solution to the original equation $x=2$.

Comment: I see what you're saying. However, squaring x does naturally change the equation somewhat. In the example I gave, we're just squaring 1 and -1.

Comment: The point is that $x^2 = y^2$ does not imply $x = y$. (In this case, $x=1$ and $y=-1$.)